# Simplify queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have queries and need to simplify them. But have no idea how. How can I do this?

```
SELECT city, SUM(weight) FROM Details
WHERE city = 'London' OR city = 'Paris'
GROUP BY city;
GO
```

```
SELECT * FROM Employees
WHERE Department = 'sales' OR Department = 'supply'
GO
```

```
SELECT * FROM Employees
WHERE (Department = 'sales' OR Department = 'supply') AND Salary >= 6000;
GO
```

Comment: They are already short. What do you want to shrink?

Comment: I don't know. It is a task.

Comment: In the first one you have "city" repeated 4 times, maybe do something like `SELECT city c...` and use "c" instead of "city" in the 3 remaining occurrences, for the second and third one use maybe IN operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `IN`:

```sql
SELECT city, SUM(weight) FROM Details
WHERE city IN ('London', 'Paris')
GROUP BY city;
```

```sql
SELECT * FROM Employees
WHERE Department IN ('sales', 'supply');
```

```sql
SELECT * FROM Employees
WHERE Department IN ('sales', 'supply') AND Salary >= 6000;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use IN

```
WHERE city IN ('London','Paris')
GROUP BY city;
GO

WHERE Department IN ('sales','supply')
GO
```